# Obtain count of all possible values of a given column in psql

Tags: psql

I have a table t1 with a column c1, which is of type character(2), and has values ranging between 00:97. I am able to count the number of cases (7632) where c1 contains a single specific value (say 62):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM t1 WHERE c1='62';
 count 
-------
  7632
(1 row)
```

However, I am interested in obtaining the count for each of the possible values (00:97) that c1 can obtain. Is there such a syntax available in psql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c1, count(*) from t1 group by c1 order by c1;
```

Comment: Thank you. I am just wondering, does this not return cases where the count was zero? And if so, is it possible to return a count of zero? (This might be a very silly question; I am just noticing numbers not adding up.)

Comment: It doesn't. Creating a query that does that too is possible, but more complicated... Do you have a table t2 which contains all possible valzes of c1?